# Python Text-Based Baseball Game - Flipping Booleans

Tags: python, list, boolean

My friend and I are making a Text-Based Baseball game in Python. We are trying to figure out how to manage the runners on base. We were thinking if the best way would be to have a list of booleans and flip them based on if the play was a single, double, etc. Any help would be appreciated!
Ex.
 `bases = [False,False,False]
if hit == single:
   bases = [True,False,False]`
We are finding it difficult considering all the possible combinations of runners on base

Comment: I was thinking that but that would flip every single one. If we had no one on base and the hit is a single, only the first one is going to flip

Comment: This question to me is super broad. There are a million ways to do it. It all depends on how your players and rules are set up...

Comment: I'm sorry but my teacher isn't an actual programming teacher. He is a Finance teacher trying to learn + teach us Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import deque
bases = [False, False, True]
playing_field = deque(bases)
print(playing_field) #deque([False, False, True])

playing_field.rotate(-1) 

print(playing_field) #deque([False, True, False])

#can use it like a list:
print(playing_field[0]) #False
```

`deque` from `collections` is perfect for what you want to do. You can basically shift the list and add a member to first base.

`rotate()` takes an integer, positive or negative, and shifts the list that many times left or right.

If I were you, make it include a home plate, so you can pop it off and score or what not. IF you need `deque` has `popleft()` and `popright()` methods to literally take the left or right most item off the list.

Comment: Wow this is so helpful I'll try this out. Very appreciated